# Datagrid binding to results from database

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid

I'm having trouble binding a wpf datagrid to data that looks like this:

```
id1   id2   result
1      10      X

1      11      Y

2      10      X

2      11      Z
```

where each row is a class instance with 3 members. So basically I have a collection of these class instances that I would like to bind to a grid that has a variable number of columns (depending on how many values 'id2' column has).

The result I'm trying to get is this:

```
id1/id2 10  11
1       X   Y   
2       X   Z
```

In some cases there can only be one column, in other cases two of them, so I have to create the columns in code behind.

I have created wrapper classes for all the row and column values(`Id1Items` and `Id2Items`), but I'm not sure where to store the result values and how to create the bindings.  Ideally I should be able to write the bindings like `"Id1Items.id1"` for the first column, and `"Id2Items.id2"` for the second column, but how should the datasource collection look like?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Have a column2 but just don't make it visible if you only have one

```
 class MyDataContext
 {  
     public string column1Name get set  // bind this to the header1 
     public string column1Name get set  // bind this to the header2       
     public bool ColumnTwoVisible get set  // bind to this to make the column2 visible or not     

     public List<MyDataRow2> MyDataSet2
 }


 class MyDataRow2
 {
     public string id get set
     public string col1 get set
     public string col1 get set
 }
```

Comment: I wouldn't like to implement the property to make second column visible or not, I would rather create the columns dynamically, but that's a small detail. I will give a try using your idea. Thanks.